# angular 5 reset nested forms

Tags: angular, forms, angular5

Angular 5

i have nested forms, like as following i had to nest forms, can some one help how can i reset nested forms.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let i of arr">
        <form>
            <input #input="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="i" required>
            <div *ngIf="input.errors.required"> required </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>

<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
<button (click)="resetForm(myForm)"></button>
```

### Component

```
...
resetForm(form: ngForm){
  form.reset();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a solution would be using [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

You could have

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <div *ngFor="let i of arr">
        <form>
            <input #input="ngModel" type="text" [(ngModel)]="i" required>
            <div *ngIf="input.errors.required"> required </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>

<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
<button (click)="resetForm()"></button>
```

and in your component

```
...
resetForm(){
  this.myFormGroup.reset();
}
...
```

that should do the trick and reset both forms.